# First Magento Module Development

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am new in Magento. I am trying to develop a custom Module. My codes are as belows

**Location:** D:\php\htdocs\magento\app\etc\modules

Remote_Mouse.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Remote_Mouse>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Remote_Mouse>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Location:** D:\php\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Remote\Mouse\etc
  config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <modules>
            <Remote_Mouse>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Remote_Mouse>
        </modules>
        <blocks>
            <mouse>
                <class>Remote_Mouse_Block</class>
            </mouse>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mouse module="Remote_Mouse">
                    <file>Remote_Mouse.xml</file> 
                </mouse>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <routers>
            <mouse>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Remote_Mouse</module>
                    <frontName>remote</frontName>
                </args>
            </mouse>
        </routers>        
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Location:**

```
D:\php\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\my_theme\default\layout
mouse.xml


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <mouse_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="remote/brush" template="remote/mouse.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </mouse_index_index>
</layout>
```

**Location:** `D:\php\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Remote\Mouse\Block`

Brush.php

```
<?php
    class Remote_Mouse_Block_Brush extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    {
        public function myfunction()
        {
            echo 'mouse';
        }
    }
```

**Location:** `D:\php\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Remote\Mouse\controllers`

IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Remote_Mouse_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout(array('default'));
        $this->renderLayout();       
    }

    public function sayHelloAction()
    {
        echo 'Hello one more time...';
    }
}
?>
```

**Location:**

D:\php\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\my_theme\default\template\remote

mouse.phtml

```
<?php
    echo $this->myfunction();
?>
```

I could not see any output. Is there any mistake in my code??

Comment: full paths to all your files should be included, especially your XML

Comment: @RobbieAverill  Thanks for your reply. I added location of the files. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with your block type you have defined as following.

```
<block type="remote/brush" template="remote/mouse.phtml" />
```

That should be as below.

```
<block type="mouse/brush" template="remote/mouse.phtml" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to run `/remote/index/index` action then you should have an error like `myfunction function does not exists`. In your layout file you used

```
<block type="core/template" name="remote_mouse" template="remote/mouse.phtml" />
```

code while there should be:

```
<block type="mouse/mouse" name="remote_mouse" template="remote/mouse.phtml" />
```

Also make sure you placed all files according to their places. If you have no errors then maybe you template or layout files not in the correct theme templates/layouts directories. Thus it was no found by the system, system not tried to render it and call `myfunction` method and so there's no error.

Also make sure the output for local modules isn't disabled.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried with your solution but it is not working. Thanks